# Add '.0' to single-digit integers

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, numeric-data

I'm trying to find the way to add a zero whenever there is a single digit.

```
750
1.75
750
50
1
32
```

The output should be like this

```
750
1.75
750
50
1.0
32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming the input file is one number per line, and you want to add `.0` to every single-digit integer:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]$/&.0/' /path/to/inputfile
```

To replace the contents of the file rather than display the changes:

```
sed --in-place 's/^[0-9]$/&.0/' /path/to/inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$0<=9{print $0".0";next}1' input.txt
```